# Strange behavior of references in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, associations, mongoid

I am using Rails 3 with Mongoid.

I have two documents:

```
class MyUser
  include Mongoid::Document

  field ......

  references_many :statuses, :class_name => "MyStatus"
end

class MyStatus
  include Mongoid::Document

  field ......

  referenced_in :user, :class_name => "MyUser"
end
```

The problem is, I can get the user of any given status, but I cannot get the list of statuses from a user!

ie.

```
status = MyStatus.first
status.user # the output is correct here

user = MyUser.first
user.statuses # this one outputs [] instead of the list of statuses...
```

Please tell me what have I done wrong? I am just a few days with mongo......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct to me.

Are you sure that MyStatus.first.user == MyUser.first ?

It's possible that you have multiple users in your db.. where the first user has no statuses, and the second user has status1 in his list.

To test this, try doing:

```
status = MyStatus.first
user = status.user 
user.statuses         # Should return at least one status
```

Comment: I didn't tested if they equal, but I did confirmed `status.user_id` equals `user.id`.....Now I have reimplemented everything and it seems working now. So maybe you're right.